# API platform generated id null, unable to generate an IRI

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I use API platform and my entities have been working for several years with the following code for example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity\AnimationCarrefour;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\SearchFilter;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiProperty;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *      collectionOperations={"get", "post"},
 *      itemOperations={"get", "put", "delete"},
 * )
 * @ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties={"carrefour": "exact"})
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Radar
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ApiProperty(identifier=true)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $numero;

   ...

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

However, for several days the generated ids have been null. The code was not modified and the database was regenerated without success.

I have the following error :

```
"title": "An error occurred",
"detail": "Unable to generate an IRI for \"App\\Entity\\AnimationCarrefour\\Radar\"."
```

Inserting the data directly into the database with an INSERT INTO without going through the API works.

Comment: Can you provide an exemple of the request you tried to run through the API ? And what do you mean by "the database was regenerated without success" ? Also can you provide more informations about the versions you're using (api platform, php, doctrine, etc)